# vertical-align in div nightmare! Any way to just get it to work without knowing div's vertical height?

Tags: jquery, css

So I've been struggling on a rather weird problem. I've tried everything from display:inline-block on spans etc., with vertical-aligns set to center and wrapping within div's with display:table and the child div as table-cell, but NOTHING seems to have any effect on vertical alignment!

I've added the code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rtKra/6/ and if you hover over the li's you'll know what I mean if the li content is on a single line it should be centered with the color box on it's left. If it spans more than two lines, it doesn't seem to matter since the top of the li is aligned with the top of the context box and the bottom exceeds to color box so it looks fine

The troublesome part is the 'space' below the 'labelDescriptor' div - should be in line with the color box on the left. If it does come in line, the content still remains aligned to the top of the div!!

The issue is the hover's background - it should be the same height as the color box on its left. Setting min-height works without a table/table-cell display, but it still has a lot of space from the bottom of the content to the bottom of the div and looks a bit off.

Simple padding doesn't cut it. Although it works for the small li's (with less content) it looks off for the ones that split over to the next line!

I've been working at it for quite a while now and have almost given up!!! I just can't seem to get anything to work!

I made the div's content wrap in < p > tags but it adds way too much space (above and below) and makes the whole thing a total mess. I don't want to blow up the font size just for the sake of it either.

Any ideas? Can it be fixed using simple css or would javascript/jquery have to be used?

The code of the html+css would get a bit too long to post here. But if the need be I could do it...

**UPDATE: ** Here is the image description of what it should look like and what I have been able to do (the fiddle url for the one on the right is  http://jsfiddle.net/rtKra/9/)

[image]

I wish to replicate the 'look and feel' of gmail's label menu as on the left. See how well aligned the text is with the 'color box' (note I don't need a full hover over the color box too). The middle image shows how the alignments are off. Would the text get centered on a div with min-height:16px it would align well. But it is NOT happening and looks visually appalling. The image on the right is what you get after changing font size to 16px and making the color box's (red) width and height = 1em and moving it down by 3px (top:3px) - The question still is all this could have been avoided by just having the content vertically center in the div in the first place. Since irrespective of the "number of lines" in the bullet it would 'align well' without having to hack it around like I've done. Hope that clarifies what I want to do :)

Comment: `.category .labelDescriptor { padding:3px }` ?

Comment: +1 For your effort in explaining and providing a fiddle. But it still is not clear to me what you precisely want. Could you provide an image of the desired result as well?

Comment: @NGLN: Check out the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rtKra/9/ Look at the last two bullets, "Font adjusted..." - the only solution I am able to go by is adjusting the size of the color box to be 1em and change the font size to about 13-14px to get the optimum height. I'm just trying to replicate Gmail's labels, and wanted the hover background to "align-well" with the colorbox. I've added a green border for reference. You'll notice how the last two bullets "look perfect" but the alignment is a bit off for the others

Comment: I thought that if I was always able to center the content of the div the 'tops' would align perfectly irrespective of the content being on one line or wrapped, without the need of manually offsetting the colorBox to get it to look right or adjust the font-size. The only "picture" i can provide is the font-adjustment. In-fact your question was exactly what I'm trying to get right :) I wish I could show you a picture, it was easier to change the font-size :) You may want to compare it with the previous fiddle though

Comment: @Nupul You want it to look [like this left picture](http://www.cellphonedigest.net/images/gmail-screenshot.jpg)? Múst the colorbox be centered vertically? If not, the problem then is to align the tops of the colorbox and the text? Show the hover background only behind the text, or behind the complete row? Must the two buttons appear next or above each other? Must the two buttons be inside or outside the width of the ul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/NPBa6/3/). Edit the font size to see the working.

The key properties are:

```
.category {
    position: relative;
}
.category .labelColorPicker {
    width: 16px; 
    height: 16px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.category .labelDescriptor {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 16px;
    min-height: 16px;
}
.category .hoverMenu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Tested on Win7 in IE8, IE9, Opera 11.50, Safari 5.0.5, FF 5.0, Chrome 12.0. I added two IE7 patch lines to the CSS, because inline-block does not work fully in IE7.

Comment: @NGLN: This is so beautiful :') sniff...+10 if I could but I dropped the zero :) so what is it that I should remember? I mean I can "see" the difference in the CSS but a short explanation of the design decision would really go a long way :) Thanks a ton!!!!!!!

Comment: @Nupul Well, the most important thing was the elimination of the `em` units for the size of the ColorPicker. Because the border width is added as pixels, you could never declare its total height in pixels, which is necessary for the min-height of the Descriptor. Also remember that vertical-align only works in conjunction with line-height. And finally, the presence of the 1px (transparent) border on the Descriptor is necessary to get no differences in total height on hover. These are the three main aspects.

Comment: @NGLN: I wansn't aware that vertical-align would work in conjuction with line height. I tried removing it and it still seemed to work fine for some reason! I was wondering about why the solid transparent border though, but I'm still not clear on how does it help compensate anything in the height...

Comment: @NGLN:...I mean why would there be a height difference if the border wasn't present? Shouldn't the element's min-height compensate for that? Or is there something (else) about CSS that I'm not fully aware of? :)

Comment: @NGLN: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah! I see :) Thanks for showing :) Really appreciate all the help! Makes a lot more sense now. Seems my CSS knowledge went up +2 :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the container to be display: table-cell and the apply vertical-align: middle to that

[check the div containing the text on the left](http://www.lampost.co.za/stylists.php)

this also drove me frikkin insane

Comment: Did you check out my fiddle? I have explicitly mentioned that even "that" is not working :) That's the first thing I actually tried...